Why do permanent magnets exert a constant force but the force from electromagnets varies between different objects?
I was testing out an electromagnet and found that force varied greatly between objects.  A thick piece of metal was very hard to pull off but thin sheet metal was very easy. I tried a few different objects and the heavier gauge metals were all attracted more strongly than the lighter ones.  However, when I put a permanent magnet on the same objects, the strength of the permanent magnet seemed to remain constant.
When I googled general information about electromagnets, nothing I found could explain what I experienced.  So then I just asked Google directly, "does the strength of an electromagnet depend on the object it is attracting?" The AI generated response was "NO" (..."the strength of an electromagnet does not depend on the object it is attracting.")
I don't know what other information I should include or what I'm doing wrong or if what I have here is enough for a question, so please be patient if I have made a faux pas and I will do whatever is necessary to fix it.

The AI was wrong, the magnetic force depends on the object it's attracting, for example, water vs iron (yes, water is slightly paramagnetic). What most likely happens is that your permanent magnet already reached nearly its pull limit (it grows nonlinearly towards a limit) but the electromagnetic hasn't therefore the electromagnet exerted a lot more force but the permanent magnet couldn't as it's close to its capacity.
